# How to resolve exception thrown while processing nested MultipartInput with RESTEasy client API?

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I have built the following JAX-RS resource which produces the desired response object that is *multipart/mixed* with nested *multipart/related* with (for now only one single) nested *application/json*.

```java
@GET
@Path("test")
@Produces("multipart/mixed")
public Response test() {
  List<Entity> entities;
  ...
  final MultipartOutput multipartOutput = new MultipartOutput();
  entities.stream().map(entity -> {
    MultipartRelatedOutput multipartRelatedOutput = new MultipartRelatedOutput();
    multipartRelatedOutput.addPart(entity, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    return multipartRelatedOutput;
  }).forEach(multipartRelatedOutput -> 
    multipartOutput.addPart(multipartRelatedOutput, MediaType.valueOf("multipart/related"))
  );
  return Response.ok(multipartOutput, MediaType.valueOf("multipart/mixed")).build();
}
```

This resource is consumed by client built with [RESTEasy client API via RESTEasy proxy framework](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.7.0.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#RESTEasy_Client_Framework). The [Response](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html)'s entity is read as [MultipartInput](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.7.0.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/multipart/MultipartInput.html). Each part's body should now be read as [MultipartRelatedInput](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.7.0.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/multipart/MultipartRelatedInput.html). As [this is not possible with my RESTEasy Version (but has been fixed in 4.5.5.Final)](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-2385), as workaround each part's body is read as [MultipartInput](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) instead.

```java
public void get()
{
  try (Response response = this.proxy.test();) {
    ...
    MultipartInput multipartInput = response.readEntity(MultipartInput.class);
    for (InputPart inputPart : multipartInput.getParts()) {
    try {
      //MultipartRelatedInput relatedInput = inputPart.getBody(MultipartRelatedInput.class, null); // not working with NPE with my RESTEasy version
      MultipartInput relatedInput = inputPart.getBody(MultipartInput.class, null);
      String json = relatedInput.getParts().get(0).getBodyAsString(); // fails
      // Entity entity = relatedInput.getParts().get(0).getBody(Entity.class, null); // also fails
    } catch (IOException exception) {}
  }
}
```

Reading the encapsulated entity as JSON-String (for simplicity, but also reading it as object with the entity's class type) fails with the following exception:

```java
Caused by: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: RESTEASY003880: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ContextParameterInjector$GenericDelegatingProxy.invoke(ContextParameterInjector.java:77)
    at javax.ws.rs.api@1.0.2.Final//com.sun.proxy.$Proxy145.getMessageBodyReader(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl$PartImpl.getBody(MultipartInputImpl.java:336)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl$PartImpl.getBodyAsString(MultipartInputImpl.java:392)
```

It looks like, that the [ResteasyProviderFactory](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.7.0.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/ResteasyProviderFactory.html)'s [contextualData](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.7.0.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/ResteasyProviderFactory.html#contextualData) is empty when *ContextParameterInjector$GenericDelegatingProxy.invoke* gets called.

**How to resolve this? Is this a bug?**

Interestingly, if I make the client method itself a JAX-RS resouce and request it from another client everything works. The [contextualData](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.7.0.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/ResteasyProviderFactory.html#contextualData) is well populated.

```java
@GET
@Path("get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void get()
{
  try (Response response = this.proxy.test();) {
    ...
    MultipartInput multipartInput = response.readEntity(MultipartInput.class);
    for (InputPart inputPart : multipartInput.getParts()) {
    try {
      MultipartRelatedInput relatedInput = inputPart.getBody(MultipartRelatedInput.class, null);
    } catch (IOException exception) {}
  }
}
```

But still the same issue, if the client method is called directly.

Environment is Windows 10 Pro 1903, OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.4_11, WildFly 17.0.1.Final, RESTEasy 3.7.0.Final.

**My most recent try** to understand what is going wrong, revealed that it is probably a bug in [resteasy-multipart-provider](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-multipart-provider). At the moment, when the first level of the multipart hierarchy is read from the response stream, the registered providers are cached in [savedProviders](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.7.0.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/multipart/MultipartInputImpl.html#savedProviders) of the [MultipartInputImpl](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.7.0.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/multipart/MultipartInputImpl.html). After reading the *MultipartInput* from the response stream, the *contextualData* is gone, but registered providers are still available for the nested *PartImpl* via *savedProviders* when reading their bodies. The Problem is, that the *savedProviders* are not populated to the next level of the multipart hierarchy on creation of the nested *MultipartInput* instances.

**My workaround for now** is to manually push the providers before and pop them after processing with [pushContext](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.7.0.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/ResteasyProviderFactory.html#pushContext-java.lang.Class-T-) and [popContextData](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.7.0.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/ResteasyProviderFactory.html#popContextData-java.lang.Class-).

```java
public void get()
{
  try (Response response = this.proxy.test();) {
    ...
    MultipartInput multipartInput = response.readEntity(MultipartInput.class);
    for (InputPart inputPart : multipartInput.getParts()) {
    try {
      MultipartInput relatedInput = inputPart.getBody(MultipartInput.class, null);
      ResteasyProviderFactory.pushContext(Providers.class, ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());
      String json = relatedInput.getParts().get(0).getBodyAsString(); // does not fail anymore
      ResteasyProviderFactory.popContextData(Providers.class);
    } catch (IOException exception) {}
  }
}
```

I will start an issue.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: @AdanayMartín As I wrote, my workaround is to make the client method itself a JAX-RS resource and request it from a wrapper method via another client. But no real solution by now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-beta-3/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html
You can see the quote

> Resteasy will automatically load a set of default providers.
> (Basically all classes listed in all
> `META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers` files). Additionally, you
> can manually register other providers, filters, and interceptors
> through the `Configuration` object provided by the method call
> `Client.configuration()`. `Configuration` also lets you set various
> configuration properties that may be needed.

So if you add the class name `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartReader` that would be enough

Comment: `MultipartReader` is already registered for the client. Checking it with `Configuration::isRegistered` returns _true_. Also re-registering the class raises `WARN: RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartReader is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.`

Comment: The above solution wont work I tried out the same with resteasy 4.5.3 client . Looks like it doesnt support multipart within a multipart.

Comment: Well, there is support for nested multiparts. Maybe not fully supported and not fully implemented. Check my update as i now think this is a bug in multipart-provider.